# Outlook 2010 some emails appearing as plain text rather than html

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010, when I recieve email from certain users, eg. mac/linux they are in plain text format. I want to force my outlook to always use html when replying (I know that their mail client can handle it) Is there anyway to do this?

thanks,

Alistair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can purchase an add-in Bells & Whistles http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/outlook-bells.html. The feature is described here. http://www.msoutlook.info/question/628

You can try a little VBA http://www.outlook-tips.net/code-samples/always-reply-using-html-code-sample/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one. Outlook always replies/forwards in the format of the original message. This is to stop you replying in HTML to someone whose email client only understands Plain Text.

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officesetupdeploy/thread/d55e55d5-f8d4-4358-85cc-cc17d5d92b51/)